# Choosing the right build and deployment tools

Tags: deployment, ant, hudson, capistrano

I have a very large, mostly HTML/SSI site that I manage part-time and do weekly deployments on in addition do being an enterprise Magento developer. The site in question has ~5000 static HTML files and requires a lot of upkeep to manage deployments.

In addition to that site, I manage numerous Magento installs. I currently manage them from SVN and do exports/checkouts from various production and qa branches/tags.

While this is manageable, I don't get some of the things that I know build tools provide. Some of those features would be:

> - Automatic Minification of CSS/JS
> - Revision History
> - Multi-server deployment
> - Runtime configuration
> - Stats of broken builds/build time/deployment frequency
> - Integration with Testing frameworks

The three tools I've been reviewing are

> - Apache Ant
> - phpUnderControl
> - Capistrano (at the insistence of a friend of mine who is a RoR dev)

I briefly looked at Hudson, and had a ton of problems trying to get it up and running.

**My Questions:**

- What is the upside/downside of going to this type of strategy?
- Any hidden pitfalls that you've experienced?
- Which tool do you think would best fit for the deployment/management of the HTML site?
- Does anyone have experience with deploying distributed Magento from a deployment/build management system?

Thanks in advance...

**Update**

Still no movement here, so I'm going to ask this:

Should I rather rebuild in HTML5 Boilerplate which has Ant build scripts out of the box? This would afford me the ability to use Ant, but the build scripts are already pre-made so I have a good starting point.  Your thoughts and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've got one more tool for you to review: Jenkins (earlyer: Hudson).

Its a great tool to run and control your builds. Furthermore you can remote the console and get notifications via Jabber protocol.

Comment: As I've mentioned, I've looked into Hudson, which is now Jenkins. I was a little less than impressed with the nightmare of an install that I had on Debian 5...